# Scala map key consists of 2 comma-separated sets. How to extract the first key in a set?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, tuples

I have a Scala map collection that looks something like this:

```
var collection = Map((A,B) -> 1)
```

The key is (A,B) and the value is 1.

My question: If I use `collection.head._1`, the result is (A,B) which is correct. But I want to extract A only, without B, as I need to compare A with some other variable. So the final result should be A stored in a different variable.

I tried to use `collection.head._1(0)` which results in error

> Any does not take parameters

Comment: (A,B) is not a set, it’s a *pair*. Correct me if I’m wrong: this question has nothing to do with the type of A and B nor with (A,B) being a key in a map, right? At that point you just have a pair (A,B) and you want the first component A… You already know how to do that… `collection.head._1._1`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
val collection = Map(("A","B") -> 1)
collection.map{ case ((a, b),v) => a -> v}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keySet` to get all the keys as a `Set[(String, String)]` and then `map` it into the first element of each:

```
  val coll: Map[(String, String), Int] =
    Map(
      ("one", "elephant") -> 1,
      ("two", "elephants") -> 2,
      ("three", "elephants") -> 3
    )

  /*
  val myKeys = coll.keySet.map { case (x, _) => x }
  // equivalent to:
  val myKeys = coll.keySet.map(tup => tup._1)
  // equivalent to: */
  val myKeys = coll.keySet.map(_._1)  // Set(one, two, three)
```